# Exclude a module from webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'd like the same functionality like RequireJS `empty:` http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

My use-case is that I include `jquery-migrate` in development, but I'd like to exclude this when built for production.

Using `IgnorePlugin` just makes it not included, and when `require`ing it in the code, it then throws an error (`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "jquery-migrate"`).

What I'd like to happen is for it to just return undefined, or something of the like (like `empty:` in RequireJS). Id like to not touch the import in the code, just configuring it to return `undefined`.

EDIT: Using `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` works, if I point the replacement to an empty file. But keeping an empty file around just for this seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use the null-loader for blanking out modules.
The noop-loader can be used for a less awkward if-else in the config.

Try:

```
rules: [{
    test: /jquery-migrate/,
    use: IS_DEV ? 'null-loader' : 'noop-loader'
}]
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me and I think answers OP's question best.  No change to code, I still have a `import foo fro 'excluded-module'` at the top of my code with no funny `if (DEV)` wrapper.  Imagine `require('excluded-module')` works just as well.

Comment: Note to other newbies, these loaders aren't included in webpack: `npm install --save-dev null-loader && npm install --save-dev noop-loader`

Comment: Is there a way without modules? I just tried ```loader: () => {}``` and I still get a can't resolve error.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to make a resolve.alias in  webpack.config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
         "jquery-migrate": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "empty-module": "jquery-migrate"
    }
}
```

Comment: This still forces me to have an empty module lying around. Cleaner than `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`, though :)

Comment: @Simen `npm i -D empty-module`

Answer (score 1):

Use Webpack's `DefinePlugin` in combination with the normal production plugins (Dedupe and Uglify).

Then in your code you can write:

```
if(DEBUG) {
    var test = require('test');
    alert(test);
}
```

And when it's built in production, the `DEBUG` will be replaced with a literal `if(false) { ... }` which will be completely removed by the uglify plugin, so `test` will only be required in a debug build.

Here's a sample Grunt task config for `grunt-webpack` that has `development` and `production` targets for the task:

```
        development: {
            devtool: "sourcemap",
            output: {
                pathinfo: true,
            },
            debug: true,
            production: false,
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    DEBUG: true,
                    PRODUCTION: false
                })
            ]
        },

        production: {
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    DEBUG: false,
                    PRODUCTION: true
                }),
                new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                    }
                })
            ]
        },
```

Comment: I actually prefer decorating source code with debug statements rather than in build tool scripts. It makes it far more understandable for yourself after coming back to the code and others when trying to understand where that jQuery-migrate is coming from.

Comment: True. This doesn't work cleanly for AMD though, at least if listed in the original `define` call. Using an alias is exactly like `empty:`, except i have to create the `empty` module myself.