# How to bundle commonjs modules except specified requires

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, browserify, commonjs

How to bundle through webpack or gulp+browserify except specified requires, for example ignore `var module = require(pathToModule);` so, that the resulting bundle also contain `var module = require(pathToModule);`

Comment: "ignore var module = require(pathToModule); so, that the resulting bundle also contain var module = require(pathToModule);" Do you want to ignore the require or include it?

Comment: "Do you want to ignore the require or include it?" - i want to ignore some requires in bundler and include it in result bundle (in my espruino there are modules like "@amperka/button" that connect via require)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with webpack [externals option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#applications-and-externals)

> You can use the `externals` options for applications too, when you want
>   to import an existing API into the bundle. I.e. you want to use jquery
>   from CDN (separate `<script`> tag) and still want to `require("jquery")`
>   in your bundle. Just specify it as `external: { externals: { jquery:
>   "jQuery" } }`.

#### webpack.config

```
{
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
}
```

---

If you want webpack to ignore the external module and keep the require statement in the output you can use a null loader

```
loaders: [{
    test: /@amperka\/.*/,
    loader: 'null'
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this decision is if there is a global vars, but in my case I need  to have some `require('module')` in result bundle - espruino himself resolves this requires

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/sheerun/external-loader) help? It allows to require and external module on disk and writes the require statement to the bundle. This also might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32061956/1787868

Comment: whatever say
`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '@amperka/buzzer' ...
`

Comment: Not sure why you get this error. could you please provide more information about your environment, sourcecode samples and detailed error (stacktrace) in you question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `externals` setting in Webpack to specify that a required module will be loaded outside of the bundle.

```js
{
  ...

  externals: {
      // require("jquery") is external and available on the global var jQuery
      "jquery": "jQuery"
  }

  ...
}
```

So then calls to `require("jquery")` from within your bundle will instead reference the global variable `jQuery` - this obviously requires that you have loaded jQuery before your bundle e.g.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```